# how do I get this regex to mimic a look-behind?

Tags: javascript, regex

```
/(([$]*)([A-Z]{1,3})([$]*)([0-9]{1,5}))/gi
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Regex running on Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/9mBU7NPR4ELDzrgv)

This is for pulling cell refs out of spreadsheet formulas and checking to see if the formula contains an absolute ref. The problem is that it's matching an invalid cell, the last one here:

```
a1
$a1
$A$5
A5*4
A20+45
A34/A$23
A1*6
A1*A45
$AAA11
AAA33
AA33:A33
$AAAAA44 // <-- not a valid cell!
```

It's matching the AAA44 in $AAAAA44, but it shouldn't. All the rest of the capture groups etc are working correctly -- each of those rows but the last one are correctly grabbing 1 or more cell refs. A negative lookahead seems like the right way to go, but after mucking with it for a good long while I must admit to being stuck.

Comment: Show us your JavaScript code, I get false for `/^(([$]*)([A-z]{1,3})([$]*)([0-9]{1,5}))$/.test("$AAAAA44")`

Comment: Because you added something to the regex.

Comment: Only start (^) and end ($), nothing fancy, what I want is to see your JS code too. Also, look into String#replace with a callback argument.

Comment: `/(([$]*)([A-z]{1,3})([$]*)([0-9]{1,5}))/.test("AAAAA1") // true` -- Adding `^` breaks it because I need to capture all instances in a line.

Comment: What're you actually trying to match? In other words, why should `$AAAAA44` fail?

Comment: @Sam I honestly think I explained that in the OP.

Comment: I just re-read it. I missed the sentence about matching cell references, continue on :)

Comment: Please note that `/[A-z]/.test('['); // true` (you're accepting chars `65` to `122`)

Comment: @PaulS. ah, yeah, good point

Comment: Just add a word boundary after the `$`: `(([$]*)\b([A-z]{1,3})([$]*)([0-9]{1,5}))`.  Also, be wary of using `[A-z]` when trying to match letters, since this character set also includes the following: `[\]^_`, and the "backtick" character, which I can't put in code because it's the delimiter for code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't match for `^...$` then you may still be able to introduce some `\b` matching

```
/foo\bbar/.test('foobar'); // false
/foo\b\d/.test('foo1');    // false
/foo\b.\d/.test('foo+1');  // true
```

So your *RegExp* would look like (I left in your capture groups)

```
var re = /(?:\b|^)((\$?)([a-z]{1,3})(\$?)(\d{1,5}))(?:\b|$)/i;
re.test('$AAAAA44'); // false
re.test('$AAA44'); // true
```

[image: debuggex]
[**Demo**](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rFmPWemABklGCJT6)

Comment: Close, but it breaks the capture of `$` in the first group. When I exec that I get undefined for the 1th capture group, which I really need, it tells me if that group is an absolute ref.

Comment: it's still skipping the first $ capture, `regex.exec("$a$34")` gives me `undefined` in the `[1]` position.

Comment: @jcollum I've updated the position of the groupings and added a group around the whole thing so it matches up more neatly with your original, please test again

Comment: Same result. Need the `$` to be in the `[1]` capture group. I went down this path a bit already with no success. `"$a$34"` and `"a$34"` are giving the same result with your code.

Comment: Sorry, looks like `\b` won't match the beginning of a string here :( **edit** give it another go?

Comment: No worries, I was a bit embarrased when it looked like you had solved it so fast.

Comment: I still think `\b` will solve your problems, I was just a bit ahead of myself with the greatness of it and only tried with `test`, now using `match` and I got it to `["$AAA44", "$AAA44", "$", "AAA", "", "44"]`